# wget download name

Tags: wget

I'd like to write a function that, given a URL, returns the name of the file downloaded by `wget URL`.

I don't understand the behavior of `wget` very well. If I do `wget` on `python.org`, `www.python.org`, `http://www.python.org`, or `http://www.python.org/`, the name of the file downloaded is `index.html`.

However, if I do `www.python.org/about`, the name of the file downloaded is `about`, instead of `index.html`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your `wget` fetches `index.html` in the first cases is because that's the default "home page" that the server points to. `python.org`, `www.python.org`, `http://www.phython.org`, and `http://www.python.org/` aren't files, so the server points `wget` to `index.html`. It points your browser there, too, though you don't usually see it. `www.python.org/about` is a different page, so it makes sense that the file it downloads has a different name.

Might I recommend the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/wget) for wget if you want to know how it works? If it's the name of the downloaded file that concerns you, you have the option to change it via the `-O` option.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I appreciate your recommendation of `-O` option, but I'd rather keep the filename. I'm still looking for how to cover all cases.

Comment: Can you better define "cover all cases"?

Comment: Sure. How would you write a function that, given a string `URL`, returns the name of the file downloaded by `wget URL`?

Comment: How about examining the logfile? Does that include the information you want?

Comment: The `--spider` option will check that the file exists without downloading it; I'm not sure what the logfile output of that would look like (`-o` option) because I'm not in a position to test it at the moment, but it might be worth looking into.